# Display remaining characters for WPF TextBox, which has limited MaxLength

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I want to display the count of remaining characters for a TextBox in a WPF user control. My instinct tells me to calculate this in the ViewModel and bind the count to a label in XAML. Somebody has to have done this before and I'd be very glad to see an example or two. I did a search, but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: You can use a ValueConverter where you pass the string and it returns the int number of remaining characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the TextBox.Text property bound to your VM?

If so, you could bind to a calculated property (who's PropertyChanged event gets raised when the .Text binding changes).

You could also use a ValueConverter.  Bind a label to the TextBox.Text property and use a ValueConverter to calculate the remaining characters.  You may need a MultiValueConverter if you need to bind/pass in the MaxLength and Text TextBox properties.

Comment: Yes, TextBox.Text is bound to the VM. Thanks for the suggestions. I'll have time to try this out tomorrow and will accept an answer after that.

Comment: I went with a ValueConverter and it works like a charm. Thanks!